# I'm looking for source code,headers and modules for kernel 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft used on the WSL 1

Tags: kernel, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers

I would like to make an experiment. I would try to install and use haxm to accelerate qemu,instead of kvm. I prefer to use the WSL 1 instead of 2,because I can't keep the hypervisor down,since haxm does not need it. So,I've configured WSL with ubuntu 16.04 and I tried to install haxm. This is what happened :

```
root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:~/Desktop/haxm/platforms/linux# make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft/build M=$PWD modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I need the source code,the headers and the modules of the kernel "4.4.0-19041-Microsoft". I see that the linux kernel for wsl 2 is here :

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel

but I haven't found the kernel for WSL 1 in any place.

Answer (score 1):

You won't.

WSL 1 was based on Microsoft's Linux-compatible kernel interface, a [compatibility translation layer](https://mikegerwitz.com/2016/04/gnu-kwindows) with [no Linux kernel](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2019/05/07/windows-terminal-and-linux-kernels.aspx) code.

WSL 2 was redesigned with a Linux kernel running in a lightweight VM environment, but you found that already.